# GraphQL Union and Input Type?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Is it possible in GraphQL to have an input type that is also a union?

Something like:

```js
const DynamicInputValueType = new GraphQLUnionType({
  name: 'DynamicInputType',
  types: [GraphQLString, GraphQLFloat, GraphQLInt]
})
```

but also able to be used as a input for a mutation?

Answer (score 21):

As of September 2017, this is not possible. There is an [ongoing discussion](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/488) around this functionality.

Comment: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/blob/master/rfcs/InputUnion.md

Comment: @jmunsch like is dead :x

Comment: @SkyzohKey https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/blob/07970a2ce5e7d2a0458d1f065a8a51fe93441258/rfcs/InputUnion.md not sure if the most up to date, but here is a version i found

Comment: They moved the RFCS into the working group repository. This is the current version as of today: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-wg/blob/21e8ecd30934843cbb175758eaa3d80325cd0929/rfcs/InputUnion.md

Comment: Is there even a workaround? How do people usually tackle this problem?

Comment: @kursus I just left a response to your comment as an answer on this question.

Answer (score 2):

As Artur mentioned, support for union input types is ongoing. Since his post, [Tagged Types](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/pull/733) were proposed as a replacement, which in turn was superseded by the [`@oneOf` directive](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/pull/825) proposal.

If you need to do this today, an alternative could be to have an input like this:

```
input AInput {
  a: String!
}

input BInput {
  b: String!
}

input DynamicInputType {
  # 'a' or 'b' — you could make a scalar instead if you'd like 
  type: String! 
  
  # Exactly one of these should be set
  a: AInput
  b: BInput
}
```

The idea here is that you define one field on this input, and then set `type` to indicate which field is set. Your resolver would probably need to validate that only the property specified by `type` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

The solution Salem suggested does work and I do use it though its not ideal because in a bunch of situations it means you need to transform the type from the query to the input type (which I think is fine to do, just annoying). This is usually the case with nested types.

If you find that is the case I would recommend restructuring your type so that

```
List {
  ListItem: ListItemVariants[]
}
```

Becomes

```
ListItem {
  ListItemVariant1: ListItemVariant1[],
  ListItemVariant2: ListItemVariant2[]
}
```

You will likely need to stick an `order` property on the variants where it is an array but it means you can mutate the item without transforming the type returned by the query so much as