# How to allow a GraphQL argument to be of multiple types?

Tags: ruby, graphql

I am using https://graphql-ruby.org .

I could not find in the docs whether it'd be possible to allow an argument to be of multiple types. ie:

My use case is, sometimes the argument may be a String when it is an ID encoded in a token. Other times may be an Integer ID.

```rb
field :search_user, UserType, 'Performs a user search' do
  argument :user_id, Integer, required: true # I'd like this to be Integer OR String
end

def search_user(user_id)
  id = user_id.is_a?(String) ? decode_id(user_id) : user_id

  User.find(id)
end
```

Is this possible? If so how can I do this?

Comment: I would make it a String always. I am not sure how "decode_id" works but `find` can/will convert an Integer represented as a String to an Integer for the purposes of querying.

Comment: Problem with making it a String is that it would not be backwards compatible with existing clients.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as a Union type. Unfortunately, the GraphQL spec doesn't currently allow having union types in inputs/arguments (see [related question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45288955/graphql-union-and-input-type)). The latest discussion on this topic is in the [RFC: OneOf Input Objects](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/pull/825).

The two ways to accomplish this are:

1. As engineersmnky suggests in the comments, use a String as the GraphQL input type. This would require the token-encoded version to have a format where you can distinctly tell whether a string is an integer in a string, or if it is a token in a string.
2. Use two arguments, such as

```rb
field :search_user, UserType, 'Performs a user search' do
  argument :user_id, Integer, required: false
  argument :user_token, String, required: false
end
```

This would require you to enforce validation of required/not required inside your resolver code. No great solutions to this issue without the GraphQL spec supporting input union types, I'm afraid!